# Better way to test (automatically) a parser?

Tags: parsing, testing, abstract-syntax-tree

I’m recently writing a small programming language, and have finished writing its parser. I want to write an automated test for the parser (that its result is an abstract syntax tree), but I’m not sure which way is better.

First what I tried is just to serialize AST to S-expression text and compare it to the expected output text I wrote by hand, but it has some problems:

- There are trivial meaningless differences between a serialized text and the expected output like whitespaces. For example, there is no difference between:

  ```
  (attribute (symbol str) (symbol length))
  ```

  (that is serialized) and:

  ```
  (attribute (symbol str)
             (symbol length))
  ```

  (that is handwritten by me) in their meanings, but string comparison distincts them of course. Okay, I could resolve it by normalization.
- When a test fails, it doesn’t show the difference between actual tree and expected tree concisely. I want to show only a difference node, not whole tree.

Second what I tried is to write S-expression parser and compare AST that parser (to be tested) generates to AST that S-expression parser (that I just implemented) generates from the handwritten expected output. However I realized that S-expression have to be tested also and it could be really nonsense.

I wonder what is the typical and easy way to test the parser.

PS. I am using Java, and dont’t want any dependencies to third-party libraries.

Comment: Couldn't you (of course recursively) compare the trees? Going over string comparision seems very pointless and error-prone. With a bit of extra work, it could also give hints where the differences start.

Comment: I tried secondly that, so I wrote expected trees (in S-expression) by hand and a S-expression parser also.

Comment: How about normalizing the S-expressions to cons pares with one parenthesis, atom, or dot per line?

Comment: I think, its rather pointless.. If you don't know the exact output of the routine what's the point of the test? Write test case to the observable and exact and/or verified output. Don't messing around with test if the parser is working unpredictably unless you are planning some kind of TDD.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Providing you are looking for a completely automated and extensible unit testing framework for your parser I'd recommend the following approach:

### Incorrect input

Create a set of samples of incorrect inputs. Then feed the parse with each of them making sure the parser rejects them. I's a good idea to provide metadata for each test case that defines the expected output — the specific error code / message the parser is supposed to produce.

### Correct input

As in the previous case, create a set of samples representing various correct inputs. Besides the simple validation that the parser accepts all inputs, there's still the problem of validating that the actual Abstract Syntax Tree makes sense.

To address this problem I'd do the following: Describing the expected AST for each test case in some well-known format that can be safely parsed — deserialized into the actual in-memory AST structures — by a 3rd party parser considered bug-free (for your case). The natural choice is XML since most languages / programming frameworks cover XML support and provide the respective (de)serialization facilities. The best solution would be to deserialize right into the AST node types. Since convenient visual editing tools for XML exist it's feasible to construct even large test cases.

Then I'd construct an AST comparer using the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) which pair-up the two ASTs and compare both nodes in each pair for equality. However, equality is a per-AST-node-type specific operation.

---

Notes:

- This approach would work with most unit-testing frameworks like JUnit.
- AST to XML serialization is a welcome tool for debugging the compiler.
- The visitor pattern implementation can easily serve as the backbone for multiple processing stages within the compiler.
- There are compiler test suites freely available that can provide some inspiration to your project — see for example the [Ada Conformity Assesment Test Suite](http://www.ada-auth.org/acats.html) for the Ada programming language, although this test suite deals with higher-level testing, not just parser testing.

Comment: When I wrote a Visual Studio extension that enabled me to use my language in real time, for me that was the de facto test. It can also provide context on the expected bounds of productions in your grammar if you add collapse-able regions. Want to know if your parser hangs in certain conditions? A live parser will very quickly tell you when this can occur because it will immediately kill the live editing session. It's also a very nice test for relative responsiveness/speed.  I've found my hand-written parser was horribly slow and took steps to improve that, now it's acceptable for certain sizes

Comment: On correctness: One means to do this is to write methods that emit a valid string of the language from the AST you parsed.  If you utilize a stripped-down version of the language where white-space is only considered as necessary, it'll pretty quickly be able to tell you whether the parse is valid.  The downside is you have then another problem: did you introduce any inconsistencies in the output from the original source text?  I'd say the XML serialization is likely the simplest version, but every method has its gotchas.

Comment: @AlexanderMorou Good point with the serialization into a string representation. However, the AST may be already have been enriched by information which is crucial for correctness verification, but can't be output into a valid string. This is why I recommended a XML (JSON, whatever structured…) serialization. But I agree that testing a serialization into the language itself has a strong reason and will be useful.

Comment: Right, the major point here would be if it's contextful or contextless.  If there is semantic data injected by the parser/lexer necessary to handle ambiguity resolution then a string of the language would be insufficient in verifying the data.  Otherwise if it's contextless, a string could provide everything you need.  Either way, automated verification of a language is tricky regardless of the method because: what if your understanding of the language isn't adequate in writing the unit test?  In writing a parser compiler, I'm finding the program knows more than I do!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what. A grammar *defines* a language. The language is the set of string that the grammar generates, or that a parser for the grammar accepts.

Given that, more than testing if the ASTs seem right, it's important to test that the parser accepts strings intended to be in the language and **rejects strings that in your mind shouldn't belong to it**.

In that sense, a simple *accept* or *reject* (bonus point for input position for the rejection) is enough to build a nice and large set of test cases.

Examples:

```
()
(a)
((((((((((a))))))))))
((((((((((a)))))))))
(a (a (a (a (a (a (b)))))))
(((((((b) a) a) a) a) a) a)
(((((((b a) a) a) a) a) a)
((a)(a)(a)(a))
((a)(a a)(a))
(())
(()())
((()())(()())(()()))
((()())()()(()()))
...
```

Comment: The definition of parsing correctly is accepting strings that belong to the language and rejecting the ones that don't. There are languages that can be well defined with a sentence in plain English; a grammar and a parser for that grammar are attempts at building machines that recognize/generate that language. Abstraction of the syntax can be done during parsing, but it doesn't have to be.